# Store multiple value in same cell

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to add a "Kudos" system in my website. I am using phpMyAdmin. When a user press a button, it gives kudos/like on a image. The table contains these columns: `id`, `user`, `photo` and `kudos`. Then I am thinking about returning the count of how many has gives kudos to that post. I am not sure how to do this, but I am thinking about store the users `id` inside the `kudos` column. But how can I store multiple names inside the cell? For example if James, Jack and John give kudos on the same post, it will say **Number of kudos: 3.**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would be better to make a join table `kudos` with columns `user_id` and `image_id` in my opinion. Every row represents a kudo. You can then use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS kudo_count FROM kudos WHERE image_id = x`

Comment: Don't use a field to store them but a separate table

Comment: @jrswgtr That sounds like a good solution. So I should store the `user_id` and `image_id` when pressing the "Give kudos" button?

Comment: @AmenCarb check my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a separate table with columns `user_id` and `image_id`. That way every row represents a kudo.

By making both columns a primary key (combined called a composite key), the combination of both creates a unique key. That way a user can't give a kudo to the same image twice!

Because I don't know the specifics of your other tables I assume you have two tables. `users` with primary key `id`, type `BIGINT(20)` and `image` with primary key `id`, type `BIGINT(20)`. If that's different you will have to change the `CREATE TABLE` statement accordingly.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kudo (
    user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    image_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, image_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES image (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

If you use `REPLACE INTO` rather than `INSERT INTO` you won't get errors when inserting a duplicate. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

To save a kudo from `user_id = 1` for `image_id = 1`:

```sql
REPLACE INTO kudo (user_id, image_id) VALUES (1,1);
```

To count all kudo's for `image_id = 1`

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS kudo_count FROM kudo WHERE image_id = 1;
```